# Protractor if (checkbox.isSelected()) bug?

Tags: javascript, selenium, checkbox, webdriver, protractor

Given the following code:

```
if (element(by.name("checkbox")).isSelected()) {
    element(by.name("checkbox")).click();
}
```

It always clicks on the checkbox no matter if it is previously selected or not, it is like it doesn't matter what it returns. I've also tried

```
if (element(by.name("checkbox")).isSelected() == true) {
    element(by.name("checkbox")).click();
}
```

same results.

But when i put the code in expected, it works like a charm... ex:

```
expect(element(by.name("checkbox")).isSelected().toBe(true));
```

gives the correct answer, if it is selected or not.

Is this a bug of Protractor or am I doing something wrong here?

PS: I have tried to run a similar code in selenium webdriver junit, and it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`isSelected()` returns a promise. You need to wait for it to complete:

```
element(by.name('checkbox')).isSelected().then(function(selected) {
    if (selected) {
        element(by.name('checkbox')).click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Good, this works, but do you have any idea why my code worked in junit? or isSelected() returns a boolean in java?

Comment: Selenium's webdriver isn't asynchronous, Protractor is

Comment: a little correction, Selenium webdriver isn't asynchronous in any language besides javascript. Selenium webdriverjs **is** asynchronous